# VBA to SaveAS with Filename, Specific Folder, and Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save file in a specific folder, add the filename, and add todays date.  My VBA is not working.  Any suggestions?

```
Sub SaveFile()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("G:\Product Support\Platinum\Agents Case Reports\Michael\Saved Client Reports\CAF\CAF Open Case Report.xlsx") & Date

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't add the date *after* the file extension, and you probably need to `Format` the date too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Public Sub SaveFile()

    Dim formattedDate As String
    formattedDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    
    Dim filename As String
    ' path + filename + formatted date + extension
    filename = _
      "G:\Product Support\Platinum\Agents Case Reports\Michael\Saved Client Reports\CAF\" & _
      "CAF Open Case Report - " & _
      formattedDate & _
      ".xlsx"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename

End Sub
```

Whenever I output a date on a filename I always make sure it will sort chronologically. In the code above this is `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`, which is year-month-day hour-minute-second. All numbers have leading zeroes, where necessary. An example from a few moments ago is "2021-08-03 17-58-59".

Answer (score 0):

File name cannot contain "/" character which is in the date you should firstly store Current Date in a variable then replace "/" from it before passing it to file name

```
Sub SaveFile()
Dim CurrentDate as string
CurrentDate = Date
CurrentDate = Replace(CurrentDate, "/", "_")
CurrentDate = Replace(CurrentDate, ".", "_")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("G:\Product Support\Platinum\Agents Case Reports\Michael\Saved Client Reports\CAF\CAF Open Case Report " & CurrentDate & ".xlsx") 
    
End Sub
```

This would work now.